# GDAL_Translate corrupts large bitmap image

Tags: geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, corrupt

I am trying to translate a large bitmap (60000 x 25000) with GDAL_Translate but it appears to corrupt the image. This works fine for smaller images but has strange results with larger ones.

I can view the image in WildBit viewer prior to translating and it has no corruption. After the translation the top of the image appears to be a repeat of the bottom of the image. Is there a way to prevent this?

I have tried the -co BIGTIFF=YES option and that has no effect.

My arguements:

```
gdal_translate.exe -of GTiff -a_nodata 0 --config GDAL_DATA "*data path*" -a_ullr tlX tlY brX brY -a_srs EPSG:3857 InputPath OutputPath
```

The end result

[image: corrupted image]

GDALInfo of input image

```
Size is 63264, 24960
Coordinate System is `'
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,24960.0)
Upper Right (63264.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (63264.0,24960.0)
Center      (31632.0,12480.0)
Band 1 Block=63264x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=63264x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=63264x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

GDALInfo of output image

```
Size is 63264, 24960
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-8500416.405268350600000,4435398.925636629600000)
Pixel Size = (0.149300716298692,-0.149018012050865)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-8500416.405, 4435398.926) ( 76d21'37.94"W, 36d58'24.22"N)
Lower Left  (-8500416.405, 4431679.436) ( 76d21'37.94"W, 36d56'48.10"N)
Upper Right (-8490971.045, 4435398.926) ( 76d16'32.49"W, 36d58'24.22"N)
Lower Right (-8490971.045, 4431679.436) ( 76d16'32.49"W, 36d56'48.10"N)
Center      (-8495693.725, 4433539.181) ( 76d19' 5.21"W, 36d57'36.17"N)
Band 1 Block=63264x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=0
Band 2 Block=63264x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=0
Band 3 Block=63264x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=0
```

Comment: Is it like that when you zoom in? I've seen similar problems with bil files but it was only in the render (draw) and was fine when zoomed in. If it is still corrupt when you zoom in then the file has a bpw doesn't it? Try something like IView http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/graphics/irfantut/commopti.html and copy the bpw to tfw for georeference.

Comment: This also happens when I zoom in. As for the next point I am a little lost. What do you mean exactly? I have tried opening the file in IView but it is too big and has memory issues.

Comment: IView has command line options, it's been over 10 years since I used them but I do remember converting rasters that couldn't be opened by ArcINFO, you may need the IView shell extension or to run in batch mode as you are correct the image is too large to open.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Ok, so I still need you to elaborate what I am doing with the image in the command line. Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "copy the bpw to tfw for georeference"

Comment: The bpw file is a world file http://webhelp.esri.com/arcims/9.3/General/topics/author_world_files.htm it's the first and last letter of the extension with a 'w' so a bitmap (.bmp) has a bpw world file, a tiff has a tfw world file and JPEG 2000 (.jp2) would be j2w for a world file, the format of the file is the same so they can be copied and renamed such that the first part of the name is the same and the extension is what is expected for a world file thus associating it. There is a utility called GeoTiff examine that can embed world coords but it's hard to find being so old.

Comment: According to the IrfanView help document a command line would look like i_view32.exe c:\test.bmp /convert=c:\test.tif to Convert file: 'c:\test.bmp' to 'c:\test.tif' without GUI but the tif will not be a GeoTiff, when you copy the world file it will be a world tif; if you don't want to have pesky world files hanging around then you can convert with gdal_translate -of gtiff which will read world tiff and write a GeoTiff (with the geotransform *inside* the file).. it seems a bit long winded but considering you can do all of this in a batch file it just needs a bit of patience and HDD space.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Mate, you are legendary. This thing had me stumped. I successfully converted the file to TIF and then the translating and warping process worked perfectly. The image even loads quicker on completion. Just for anyone else reading, I used the i_view64.exe instead.

Comment: Awesome, it's nice to know that trick still works. Can you put in the steps you used as an answer to your own question for someone else (perhaps in another 10 years) who has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested the process I followed to overcome this issue was

1. Run i_view64.exe with the following command

   ```
   i_view64.exe InputImage.bmp /convert=OutputImage.tif
   ```
2. Run GDAL_Translate

   ```
   gdal_translate.exe -of GTiff -a_nodata 0 --config GDAL_DATA "*data path*" -a_ullr tlX tlY brX brY -a_srs EPSG:3857 InputPath.tif OutputPath.tif
   ```
3. I then proceeded on to use GDALWarp.exe but that is beyond the issue here.

The output of this was a successfully geo-referenced image based on a large bitmap.